# C++ change multiple strings into an enum

Tags: c++, string, boost, types, enums

I'm working on a legacy code base where a header file has defined 5 strings like so:

```
#define NUM_STRINGS 5
extern string string_0;
extern string string_1;
extern string string_2;
extern string string_3;
extern string string_4;
```

and in a cpp file somewhere else:

```
string string_0 = make_string("my_string_0");
string string_1 = make_string("my_string_1");
string string_2 = make_string("my_string_2");
string string_3 = make_string("my_string_3");
string string_4 = make_string("my_string_4");
```

Now in the codebase these strings are used as function parameters, in that we have a function `void func(string str)` where str is always one of these 5 strings. Is there a way to throw these strings into a type, say string_enum, that

1. will get the correct string out of the type at [near] zero-cost
2. guarantees someone can't call `func("hello world")`
3. allows me to get the number of elements in the enum
4. anything else helpful you want to mention

Comment: `string string_0 = new string("my_string_0");` - you can't have code like that - it would not compile. Post the real code.

Comment: Prefer a `const unsigned int NUM_STRINGS = 5;` to `#define NUM_STRINGS 5` and any time you have variables numbered 1 to N what you really want is an array of N elements.

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std` in a header.

Comment: @NeilButterworth the strings are statically constructed inside some function that I haven't actually found yet. The new was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to throw these strings into a type, say string_enum, that
>
> 1. will get the correct string out of the type at zero-cost

Not really zero-cost, but quite efficient: Use a `std::map<std::string, my_enum>`:

```
enum my_enum {
    my_string_0 ,
    my_string_1 ,
    my_string_2 ,
    my_string_3 ,
    my_string_4
};

const std::map<std::string,my_enum> enumMap = {
    { "my_string_0" , my_string_0 } ,
    { "my_string_1" , my_string_1 } ,
    { "my_string_2" , my_string_2 } ,
    { "my_string_3" , my_string_3 } ,
    { "my_string_4" , my_string_4 }
};
```

> 2. guarantees someone can't call func("hello world")

Check for existence of the string in the map's keys, and throw an exception from `func()` in case it doesn't exist:

```
void func(const std::string key) {
    if(enumMap.find(key) == std::end(enumMap)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("key");
    }
}
```

> 3. allows me to get the number of elements in the enum

```
std::size_t getNumKeys() {
    return enumMap.size();
}
```

Comment: Think this would be easier to pull off with a `std::set`. It eliminates the need for the `enum` entirely

Comment: I like this, although wouldn't I make the enum the key and the string the value?

Comment: @Robert Depends on your needs. Your question sounded just like you need it otherwise.